# Looking For My Glasses

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase to describe the situation like looking for one's glasses, where accomplishing the objective would make the task easier to complete in the first place? Is it just irony?

Comment: *Working at a disadvantage*?

Comment: "It's like when you're looking for your glasses."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider **buried shovel**:

> A tool that is required to perform a certain task, but that is only available after you complete that task.

([Word Spy](http://logophilialimited.com/index.php?word=buried-shovel))

This is a bit different from the way you phrased the question: the tool does not merely *facilitate* things, but is actually *required* for the job.

Example:

> I can't see very well. I need glasses to find my glasses. It's a **buried shovel** situation.

Answer (score 8):

**catch-22**

> 1. :  a problematic situation for which the only solution is denied by a circumstance inherent in the problem or by a rule ; also :  the circumstance or rule that denies a solution
>
> [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch-22)

Comment: The supreme irony. +1.

Comment: One more example for this would be: To get a position in a research lab, you need experience and to gain experience, you need a research lab. If you're thinking, yes it's my personal agony.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stretch, but you can possibly use the term [*paradox*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradox):

> something (such as a situation) that is made up of two opposite things and that seems impossible but is actually true or possible - Merriam Webster

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research in your post. I would advise you to take the tour and visit our help center to see how it works here.  One suggestion for your answer: Add an illustrative sentence using "paradox" that fits the OPs example of searching for his glasses.